# Select youtube video quality in android videoView

Tags: android, video, youtube, android-videoview

I using code on link for playing YouTube video in videoView.

When I play video the quality is not good enough. How can I chose the quality of the video?

Code link: http://developerandro.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-videoview.html?showComment=1390130072271#c2150603475475337907

Answer (score 0):

Youtube will deliver a low quality video if it detects a mobile device or a slow Internet connection, to bypass that, you can try to change the user agent to a desktop browser, ex:

```
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
```

Comment: This is for webView do you have any idea how to bypass for videoView

Comment: You don't need to use videoView to play a youtube videos, webView will do it. Just make sure you had `android:hardwareAccelerated = "true"`to your activity on the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: I do not want to play it in browser. Because I do not want to get all images of different movies at the end. And I also need to catch when movie stops playing. And I want all control about movie playing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [YouTube Android Player API.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) It uses the native YouTube app, and works pretty well. 
It won't allow you to set the quality of the video, but I believe it shows a 'HD' button for the user to enable.

I believe it'll also set the quality to HD automatically when the device/connection are fast enough to handle it.

Comment: I do not want to put in to YouTube Android Player API because I use this in a library.